# How to receive csv or pdf file as response of a ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am using Django.

I need to receive a pdf, csv or xls file as a reponse to a form I am submitting through ajax.

It is receiving the file when I am normally submitting the form, but when I do it through ajax it receives it but dosen't show download option.

I want to submit it through ajax to show a loading .gif as it take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The data that you get back from an AJAX request is really nothing more than text data. I don't think this is an easy thing to accomplish. What is the reason for the AJAX? Is it a long running process to generate? If it is then you can do a redirect in your javascript when the .csv or .xls is generated. If your doing the AJAX to just keep the user on the same page, then I would try submiting the form to a new target window.

Comment: thanks for the answer @ek_ny actually i have to show a loading gif thats why i thought i should use ajax so that i can show the gif before request is sent and hide it after response is arrived. Please help me out here I am struck. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

create a hidden iframe, then in your ajax :

url: document.getElementById('myiframeid').src = your_server_side_url,